# php get today tomorrow and next day but ignore weekends

Tags: php, date

How can I get the current day, tomorrow and next day in PHP but ignore weekends?

I have already tried this code, but it will include Saturday and Sunday.

```
array(
    'todayDate' => date('d/m/Y')
    'tomorrowDate' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime(' +1 day')),
    'nextDay' => date('l', strtotime(' +2 day'))
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Weekday(s)` with `strtotime`

```
date('l', strtotime(' +2 Weekdays'));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/378716)**

Answer (score 2):

This finds the next weekday from a specific date (not including Saturday or Sunday):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2011-04-05 +2 Weekday'));
```

You could also do it with a date variable of course:

```
$myDate = '2011-04-05';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($myDate . ' +2 Weekday'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Get date between two date without weekdays(Saturday and Sunday).

$startdate = '10-06-2015';

$endDate = '17-06-2015' ;

$Workingdays = getdateBettwoDate($startdate,$endDate);

print_r($Workingdays);

function getdateBettwoDate($startdate,$enddate)
    {

```
    $start    = new DateTime($startdate);
    $end      = new DateTime($enddate);
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    $x=0;
    $a=array();      
    foreach ($period as $dt)
    {
        $temp=$dt->format("l d-m-Y");
        $ArTemp=explode(' ',$temp);
        if($ArTemp[0]=='Saturday' || $ArTemp[0]=='Sunday'){
        }else{
          $a[$x]=$ArTemp[1];
           $x++ ;
        }


    }       
    $a[$x]=date('l', strtotime( $enddate))." ".$enddate;
    return $a ;
}
```